# NTP client for Linux in C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu-20.04, ntp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    int recvsize;
    char pack[1024];

    struct sockaddr_in sAddr;
    struct hostent *sHost;

    sHost = gethostbyname("time.google.com");
    if(sHost == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    memset(&sAddr, 0, sizeof(sAddr));
    sAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;


    memcpy(&sAddr.sin_addr, sHost->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(sAddr.sin_addr));
    sAddr.sin_port = htons(123);

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sAddr, sizeof(sAddr)) == -1){
        perror("connect error");
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Connect" << std::endl;

    recvsize = recv(sock, pack, sizeof(pack), 0);

    std::cout << "Get Size:" << recvsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << pack << std::endl;
    
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code for a ntp client.
I try to connect and get daytime message from ntp server.

But when I run this code, Nothing is going to happen.
The connection seems to be working, and no connection failures or timeouts seem to be occurring.

My Environment:
Main OS: Windows10
Sub OS: ubuntu20.04 LTS (running  in VirtualBox 6.1)
Compiler: g++ 4.8.4

Add a description:
I'm sorry I forgot to add the header.
It show "Connect",when this program run.
And, Goes into standby mode without exiting. It's not freezing.

Comment: why do you provide samples without headers? is it so hard to publish complete code? after so many years still the same...

Comment: So the program ends without an error output *or* a success output? And: Did you run the code in a debugger?

Comment: If nobody answers, i should point that code hangs at this line "sHost = gethostbyname("time.google.com");"

Comment: @SChepurin - This code is complete code. This is just a code to confirm the connection method.

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica - No, program isn't end. Stops while waiting to receive.

Comment: @tkm-knj You should report (by editing the question!) exactly what happens when you run the program: Does it hang? Does it crash? Does it end silently? Does it end with an output? If yes, what's the output? What is the exit code?

Comment: Ah, OK. Then you have to follow the advice given in the answer: Read the NTP spec in the RFC, or read one of the surely available NTP tutorials and examples, or watch a video of somebody explaining it, in the order of preference.

Comment: i already said - it cannot get-host-by-name and returns NULL

Comment: After it gets name - socket is not created. And so on...

Comment: @tkm-knj - "This code is complete code" - nope. The complete code includes headers. And small, but priceless advice: do not trust sample code you copy - if it does not work as expected (for different reasons), add simple couts or printfs to be sure.

Comment: @SChepurin Why are you so sure that that call does not work? Granted, I'd like to see an error message and non-zero return value when it fails, but the program *would* end and not proceed to the `recv` call, right?

Answer (score 3):

You are just opening a UDP socket to an NTP server. In order to properly interact with an NTP server, you need to implement the protocol.

The latest version of NTP is specified in [RFC5905](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5905). There you will find all the information you need. Alternatively, you could look at the [reference implementation](https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp) of the ntp-project.

If you want to verify that your code is creating an outgoing connection you can check with `netstat -puw | grep 123`. This command lists all outgoing UDP connections and filters all lines not containing 123. On Ubuntu, you need the `net-tools` package to be installed to run this command.

Comment: I think the OP's issue is more basic: They are not sure whether the connection was established at all.

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica - "They are not sure whether the connection was established at all." - and what is if(connect) for in this sample from manual (he/she copied it for sure)?

Comment: I assumed it was clear that a connection has been established since the code is checking for a connection error. I think the issue is that OP was expecting something to happen without implementing the protocol on top of the socket.

Comment: @user2393256 - "I assumed it was clear that a connection has been established" - nope. He/she is not sure if it gets server by name, and it is not. Even if it does (when corrected), the socket is not created.

Comment: I did the netstat command and it was in ESTABLISHED state.